# Why the item of linq request is Null in the code?

Tags: c#, .net

My Code was running fine and then today the item request is null empty and every line is fine. I didn't understand why the item is null, this is my code on the controller

```
public ActionResult Listquittancier()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Listquittancier(DateTime datedebut, DateTime datefin)
{
    test_devEntities db = new test_devEntities();

    var item = db.QUITTANCIER
                    .Where(x => x.DATE_MVT_DU >= datedebut && x.DATE_MVT_DU <= datefin)
                    .Take(10) ;

    return View(item);
}
```

Comment: DateTime datedebut and DateTime datefin are changed?

Comment: What are the values of DATE_MVT_DU in the database?  What is the date value of datebut and datefin?  It is possible that this query returns no results as there is no records that fall into this date range

Comment: There can be multiple reasons. First check if you even have any data in the database. Most likely your datedebut and datefin are changed and there is just no data available in that range.

Comment: May you tell use the value of datedebut and datefin? And is there at least one data in this range?

Comment: I checked my data base all is fine and for datedebut and datefin are changed in the query and there are results when i checked with sql query from 01-12-2012 to 31-12-2012 there are a data but the query doesn't give me results . i didn't find the cause

Comment: @OussamaHsini var item = db.QUITTANCIER works?

Comment: could you debug and confirm that the correct Listquittancier method is being called?

Comment: db.QUITTANCIER works supposly how do i know if it doesn't work .

Comment: Listquittancier is being called . oucch . what'es the problems guys

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very good write in this context ... but the causes can be:

- don't arrived this (DateTime datedebut, DateTime datefin) and are
  null
- in database isn't nothing in this interval of dates.

Make a debug of code for POST call and check the query in database as solutions.

Comment: datedebut and datefin are not null and between what i include in datefin and datedebut there are many informations . I tried it in the sql query section and it works and there are results

Comment: ok ... in this case make this sample test because I thing you have problem with DB Context. db.Database.Exists() or Select first row from table

Comment: another thing .. check the string connection is the same? Or the date format is incorrect ...